# 2D curve fitting in Julia

Tags: julia, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I have an array `Z` in Julia which represents an image of a 2D Gaussian function.  I.e. `Z[i,j]` is the height of the Gaussian at pixel i,j.  I would like to determine the parameters of the Gaussian (mean and covariance), presumably by some sort of curve fitting.

I've looked into various methods for fitting `Z`: I first tried the `Distributions` package, but it is designed for a somewhat different situation (randomly selected points).  Then I tried the `LsqFit` package, but it seems to be tailored for 1D fitting, as it is throwing errors when I try to fit 2D data, and there is no documentation I can find to lead me to a solution.

> How can I fit a Gaussian to a 2D array in Julia?

Comment: What did you try for LsqFit? It's certainly possible to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to use Optim.jl. Here is an example code (it was not optimized for speed, but it should show you how you can handle the problem):

```
using Distributions, Optim

# generate some sample data    
true_d = MvNormal([1.0, 0.0], [2.0  1.0; 1.0 3.0])
const xr = -3:0.1:3
const yr = -3:0.1:3
const s = 5.0
const m = [s * pdf(true_d, [x, y]) for x in xr, y in yr]

decode(x) = (mu=x[1:2], sig=[x[3] x[4]; x[4] x[5]], s=x[6])

function objective(x)
    mu, sig, s = decode(x)
    try # sig might be infeasible so we have to handle this case
        est_d = MvNormal(mu, sig)
        ref_m = [s * pdf(est_d, [x, y]) for x in xr, y in yr]
        sum((a-b)^2 for (a,b) in zip(ref_m, m))
    catch
        sum(m)
    end
end

# test for an example starting point
result = optimize(objective, [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0])
decode(result.minimizer)
```

Alternatively you could use constrained optimization e.g. like this:

```
using Distributions, JuMP, NLopt

true_d = MvNormal([1.0, 0.0], [2.0  1.0; 1.0 3.0])
const xr = -3:0.1:3
const yr = -3:0.1:3
const s = 5.0
const Z = [s * pdf(true_d, [x, y]) for x in xr, y in yr]

m = Model(solver=NLoptSolver(algorithm=:LD_MMA))

@variable(m, m1)
@variable(m, m2)
@variable(m, sig11 >= 0.001)
@variable(m, sig12)
@variable(m, sig22 >= 0.001)
@variable(m, sc >= 0.001)

function obj(m1, m2, sig11, sig12, sig22, sc)
    est_d = MvNormal([m1, m2], [sig11 sig12; sig12 sig22])
    ref_Z = [sc * pdf(est_d, [x, y]) for x in xr, y in yr]
    sum((a-b)^2 for (a,b) in zip(ref_Z, Z))
end

JuMP.register(m, :obj, 6, obj, autodiff=true)
@NLobjective(m, Min, obj(m1, m2, sig11, sig12, sig22, sc))
@NLconstraint(m, sig12*sig12 + 0.001 <= sig11*sig22)

setvalue(m1, 0.0)
setvalue(m2, 0.0)
setvalue(sig11, 1.0)
setvalue(sig12, 0.0)
setvalue(sig22, 1.0)
setvalue(sc, 1.0)

status = solve(m)
getvalue.([m1, m2, sig11, sig12, sig22, sc])
```

Answer (score 2):

In principle, you have a loss function

```
loss(μ, Σ) = sum(dist(Z[i,j], N([x(i), y(j)], μ, Σ)) for i in Ri, j in Rj)
```

where `x` and `y` convert your indices to points on the axes (for which you need to know the grid distance and offset positions), and `Ri` and `Rj` the ranges of the indices.  `dist` is the distance measure you use, eg. squared difference.

You should be able to pass this into an optimizer by packing `μ` and `Σ` into a single vector:

```
pack(μ, Σ) = [μ; vec(Σ)]
unpack(v) = @views v[1:N], reshape(v[N+1:end], N, N)
loss_packed(v) = loss(unpack(v)...)
```

where in your case `N = 2`. (Maybe the unpacking deserves some optimization to get rid of unnecessary copying.)

Another thing is that we have to ensure that `Σ` is positive semidifinite (and hence also symmetric). One way to do that is to parametrize the packed loss function differently, and optimize over some lower triangular matrix `L`, such that `Σ = L * L'`.  In the case `N = 2`, we can write this as

```
unpack(v) = v[1:2], LowerTriangular([v[3] zero(v[3]); v[4] v[5]])
loss_packed(v) = let (μ, L) = unpack(v)
    loss(μ, L * L')
end
```

(This is of course prone to further optimization, such as expanding the multiplication directly in to `loss`).  A different way is to specify the condition as constraints into the optimizer.

For the optimzer to work you probably have to get the derivative of `loss_packed`.  Either have to find the manually calculate it (by a good choice of `dist`), or maybe more easily by using a log transformation (if you're lucky, you find a way to reduce it to a linear problem...).  Alternatively you could try to find an optimizer that does automatic differentiation.

Comment: A nice explanation - this goes along the implementations I gave above. The only additional issue in this problem is to check that covariance matrix is valid.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's a good point. One could avoid it by instead using a parameter `S` with `Σ = S^2` (right?). That just makes differentiation more complicated.

Comment: And `Σ` must also be positive semidefinite.

Comment: I thought that sigma having a square root implies it being positive semidefinite? Or am I reading [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Positive_semidefinite) wrong? (My linear algebra might be a bit rusty, I have to admit...)

Comment: This is indeed a good point. You would have to set `Σ = S*transpose(S)` and then it would be simplest to have `S` to be triangular so that you have three parameters to estimate.